# How to create a a gzip file a database with its unique folder using mongodump command?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I want to take a backup of the database into a specific folder which does not exists into my folder directory every time I have to dump any database I want the command will create the folder to save the gzip database in it I have tried the below command:

```
1. mongodump --db sh_2 -o path/of/folder
```

First command will only dump the files for the collections. it also create the directory which is not exists it will create it first then dump the database

```
2. mongodump --db sh_2 --gzip --archive=/path/of/folder
```

Second will only dump the database with gzip extension and created only one file but not a specific directory which does not exists.

I want the single command which do the work of that two both commands which I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Below batch will create a dynamic folder each time you call it. If you are on windows you can create a task schedule to call this script periodically to create backup sets.

```
@echo OFF
:: This will create a timestamp like yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss.
set BACKUPNAME=C:\BackupFolder
set BACKUPNAME=%BACKUPNAME%\%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%
@echo BACKUPNAME=%BACKUPNAME%
PATH "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin"
:: Create a new directory
md "%BACKUPNAME%"
echo Running backup "%BACKUPNAME%"
mongodump --db mydatabasename --gzip -o "%BACKUPNAME%"
```